# Rails OmniAuth failing signin routes production ENV

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes, omniauth, koala

I have an app which you can log into using facebook. This uses Omniauth and koala which all works nicely in developement ENV.

However, in production mode deployed to a subURI, my action and routes for signing in fails. The deployed URL looks like so and code as follows:

```
www.domain_name/rails_app
```

When attempting to log in url goes to

```
www.domain_name/auth/facebook
```

not

```
www.domain_name/rails_app/auth/facebook
```

routes.rb

```
  match 'auth/:provider/callback', to: 'sessions#create' 
  match 'auth/failure', to: redirect('/')
  match 'signout', to: 'sessions#destroy', as: 'signout'
```

Login action homepage.html.erb

```
<b><%= link_to "Sign in with Facebook", "/auth/facebook", id: "sign_in" %></b>
```

I have tried

```
match 'auth/:provider/callback', to: 'sessions#create', as: "signin"
```

and using `signin_path` instead of `/auth/facebook` but this errors out with missing action in sessions#create.

Is there a way to properly map  `match 'auth/:provider/callback', to: 'sessions#create'` to a path like login_path?`

Answer (score 0):

try this - write in your production.rb file

```
DOMAIN_CONFIG = "http://www.domain_name/"  
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => "http://www.domain_name" }
```

Comment: Hi Dipak, how come its action mailer? and should it be domain_name.eu/rails_app or just domain_name?

Comment: hmm that hasn't done anything either unfortunately. Is there a way to map that match 'auth/:provider/callback', to: 'sessions#create' to a proper route path? like login_path?